# Raising Power Factor [Lagging] Using Resistive Loads

Tags: motor, power-electronics, three-phase

I am wondering ***why*** to bother myself and go look for capacitors to raise pf (lagging) while I can do this by just using more resistors in the load.

Yes, as it might appear to you, **my idea is math rooted**. The more real power absorbed by the load in the circuit, the **less significant** the reactive power (it) becomes.

Pf = cos (theta) where theta = arctan( Q/P); theta gets closer to 0 as P increases. This means pf approaches 1.

My question seems *too* basic and this is on purpose. I really need to know **why** this has not been adapted and adding **more details** would be so awesome.

**UPDATE**: Would not this choice between using Rs and Cs depend on ***cost analysis***? i.e, there may be situations where I can use Rs to have more efficient system than just using Cs... or a combination of both..?

Comment: You only start to care about pf correction when it costs you a lot (or you are required to do so by regulation where your point would not apply anyways)

Comment: Next time you decide to spend time on formatting, concentrate on formulas instead of applying bold to random words.

Comment: I respect your opinion and I will do better next time but you are ignorant of the fact that I made them bold on purpose and not just on random basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I really need to know why this has not been adapted and adding more details would be so awesome.

- Because the user would have to pay for the power used.
- Because the user would have to pay for a larger contracted supply, transformer, cables and switchgear.
- Because voltage drop would increase.
- Because the power dissipated in the resistors would have to be removed.
- Because it would be wasteful (environmentally and every other way).
- Because it's not solving the problem - it's hiding it at great expense.
- Because capacitor power-factor correction works, does not dissipate sinificant heat, solves the original problem, reduces losses on the whole network and reduces the consumer's bills by eliminating power-factor surcharge.

> Would not this choice between using Rs and Cs depend on cost analysis? i.e, there may be situations where I can use Rs to have more efficient system than just using Cs or a combination of both?

How could it be more efficient if you are wasting power as heat? You pay for power-factor correction capacitor bank once. You would pay for your resistive load continuously. Let's say your energy cost is low at 10c per kWh and there are 8760 hours in a year then each kW of load is going to cost 876 (whatever currency you are using) per year.

If you wish to include some sample numbers with your question we can work it out. Include the local energy cost too.

[image]

*Figure 1. Phasor diagram showing the two cases.*

Comment: Wow, I did not expect that resistors do all of that. But, please, see my "update" in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer but I encourage you to un-accept for a day or two to encourage others to respond. You'll often get some other angles which will improve your understanding.

Comment: The majority of people do only pay for real power delivered and don't need to care about of on their devices. It only gets significant in industrial settings where you do

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Understood, but the fact that OP is asking suggests that it's a problem.

Comment: @Transistor: in virtually all cases where I had to worry about pfc, it was for reasons of governmental regulations

Comment: @PlasmaHH: One of my duties is to look after an industrial supply of several MVA in Ireland (and I believe the arrangement is the same across most of Europe). Substantial financial penalties apply if power factor falls below 0.95. This provides an incentive to the users to correct the power factor as above 0.95 there are no penalties and there's enough slack there that the power-factor correction doesn't have to be exact. In our case the energy regulator sets the tarriffs but this is just because of deregulation. In the old days the monopoly utility used to set the tarriffs themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to reduce conductive losses from reactive loads.

Correcting the power factor is not a solution, if it means adding Real load current to make the reactive current ratio look small.